# Access SOAP message header in the requested method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, handler

EDIT : Message cleared and code added

I develop a jax-ws based web service with a basic Java client.

I use SOAP handlers to authenticate the user. One on the client side which add the userId and the token to the SOAP header and another one on the server side which get these informations and authenticate the user with the database.

Client side (simplified) :

```
import static modules.auth.AuthClient.userID;
import static modules.auth.AuthClient.token;

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    //Getting SOAP headers
    SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
    SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();

    QName qname;
    SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement;

    //Add userID in SOAP header
    qname = new QName("****","UserID");
    soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);
    soapHeaderElement.setActor(SOAPConstants.URI_SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);
    soapHeaderElement.addTextNode(userID);

    //Add token in SOAP header
    qname = new QName("****","Token");
    soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);
    soapHeaderElement.setActor(SOAPConstants.URI_SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);
    soapHeaderElement.addTextNode(token);

    soapMsg.saveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Server side (simplified) :

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {  
    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (!isRequest) {
        //Getting SOAP headers
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();

        Iterator it = soapHeader.extractHeaderElements(SOAPConstants.URI_SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);

        Node userIDNode = (Node) it.next();
        String userID = (userIDNode == null) ? null : userIDNode.getValue();

        Node tokenNode = (Node) it.next();
        String token = (tokenNode == null) ? null : tokenNode.getValue();

        //Return if the user is connected
        User u = AuthWS.validToken(userID, token);

        //Here I have my user but I don't know how to get it in my requested method
    }
    return true;
}
```

In order to manage users rights I would like to access my user directly in the method requested.

Example of method that can be requested :

```
public Project getProject(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) throws WebServiceFailure, EntityNotFoundException {

    //Here I would like to verify the user's rights

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = DBConnect.getStatement("SELECT name FROM projects WHERE name = '" + name + "'");
        ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();
        if(res.next()){
            Project p = new Project(res.getString("name"));
            ps.close();
            return p;
        } else {
            ps.close();
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find the project '"+name+"'");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new WebServiceFailure(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: in your SOAP handler, you can get the servlet request object from the `SOAPMessageContext`. you can then set your userID by using `request.setAttribute()`.

Comment: This kind of question is on-topic, but you need to be more specific about what you are trying to do and what you've tried that didn't work for you. What sort of environment is your service running in? What are the inputs to "the requested method"?

Comment: please add the code which you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found exactly what I was searching for :

[Follow this link.](http://gcmuganda.faculty.noctrl.edu/classes/Spring12/615/Lab4/CSC615Spring12MessageHandlersLab.html)

In the section "Passing Information from the Handler Level to the Application"